# How to send image files to/from server

Tags: c#, sql-server, bitmap, sql-server-2012

I want to implement the following two services:
 (using web api for the matter)

1. get picture from server.
2. add new picture to the server.

The server store pictures in the DB iun varbinary.
The pictures can be bmp, jpg, ico

my function signature is

```
AddIcon(string Id, byte[] IconFile)
```

And then I thought of inserting it to the db.
Now, if I pass BitmapImage through my DTOs, I need to have references to many objects and I don't think it is the best practice. That is why I prefer byte[].

1. Is there a way to convert BitmapImage to Byte[] without knowing its structure?
2. When retrieving the file, is there a way to convert Byte[] back to BitmapImage without knowing its structure (like when loading from disk)
   Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "IIS"? Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BitmapImage is optimized and it hides details like codec info. You can use:

```
    public static byte[] SaveToPng(this BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        return SaveWithEncoder<PngBitmapEncoder>(bitmapSource);
    }

    private static byte[] SaveWithEncoder<TEncoder>(BitmapSource bitmapSource) where TEncoder : BitmapEncoder, new()
    {
        if (bitmapSource == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmapSource");

        using (var msStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var encoder = new TEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
            encoder.Save(msStream);
            return msStream.ToArray();
        }
    }


    public static BitmapSource ReadBitmap(Stream imageStream)
    {
        BitmapDecoder bdDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        return bdDecoder.Frames[0];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I do it without an encoder? can't I treat it as if its type is unknown to me? When I load the image from the disk I just give it a path . So when I get it from a socket, why do I need to choose an encoder?

Comment: How do I create BitmapImage back from byte[]

Comment: BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(image bytes from your db)
bi.EndInit();